# how to import a file to append the existing graph using gephi toolkit?

Tags: import, append, toolkit, gephi

if i have imported a file to a container, and i want to append another file to previous file to generate a bigger graph using gephi toolkit?

```
    File graphmlFile = new File("f:\\test1.graphml");
    File graphmlFile1 = new File("f:\\123.graphml");
    // Init a project - and therefore a workspace
    ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
    pc.newProject();
    Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

    // get import controller
    ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);

    //Import file
    Container container = importController.importFile(graphmlFile);
```

then i want to import graphmlFile1 to append graphmlFile,how can i do it?